# im getting a logical error, how can i fix this?

Tags: python, version, python-3.9

```
n = int(input("Enter N number : "))
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]
print("\nList is : ", a)
list1=a
list1.sort()
print("Smallest element is:", min(list1))
print("Largest element is:", list1[-1])
def Average(list1):
    return sum(list1) / len(list1)
list1=a
average = Average(list1)
print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
element=int(input("Enter a number to count how many times is repeated: "))
list1.count(element)
print("\nNumber is repeated" ,element , "times")
```

how can i fix this logical error ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVyy0.png)

my results show this:
Enter N number : 5

Enter the numbers : 1 2 3 4 5

List is :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Smallest element is: 1
Largest element is: 5
Average of the list = 3.0
`enter code here`Enter a number to count how many times is repeated: 3

Number is repeated 3 times

Comment: Do `repeats = list1.count(element)` and put `repeats` in your `print()`  call instead of `element`.

Comment: got it!! print("\nNumber is repeated" ,list1.count(element) , "times")

Comment: this workss perfect! ==> print("\nNumber is repeated" ,list1.count(element) , "times")

Comment: how can i do that in my code?? Insert the new value 130 in the index 3 without deleting the old value at that index

Comment: And wy do you do `list1=a`? If you want the list to be known as `list1` then create it with this name. If you thought you get a copy of list `a` with that: you don't. You still have one list, but you can access it under 2 different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `list1.count(element)` statement at all. You count the number of elements in the list, but you never pass it into `print` statement. Instead, you pass `element` which is the input provided.

```
list1.count(element)
print("\nNumber is repeated" ,list1.count(element) , "times")
```